# Generating unique random numbers in Excel using formula without VBA

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I have to generate five distinct random numbers from 0 to 50 using only formulas and not VBA. How should I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming A1 is blank or a text header you can use this "array formula" in A2

`=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:51"))-1)=0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:51"))-1),INT(RAND()*(51-ROWS(A$2:A2)+1)+1))`

confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so that curly braces like { and } appear around the formula in the formula bar, now copy to A6

That will generate 5 integers from 0 to 50 without repeats

Comment: How to change if we want 1 - 38

Answer (score 1):

You may want to round the following depending on your use.

```
=RAND() * 50
```

Comment: or `=ROUND(RAND()*50,0)` if they need to be whole numbers (integers)

Comment: ...but I think the requirement is for 5 `distinct` numbers - this method used in 5 different cells won't guarantee that they are distinct - see my suggestion