# How long will it take to generate approximately 1,600 non-duplicative random numbers using excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have what I think is an interesting question hopefully someone can answer.

Im using the randbetween formula in excel to randomly generate approximately 1300 numbers. I would like these numbers to be non-duplicative so I created a column to countif....whe the sum of the countifs equal the exact number I am trying to generate (1300) a statement in a different cell will say STOP. I am using a Do Until Loop to refresh the screen until the cell says STOP.

Do you know, statistically, how long this would take?

Column A
=IF(R2="C",RANDBETWEEN(1,1364)," ")

Column B
=IF(A2<>" ",COUNTIF(A:A,A2)," ")

Cell C2
=IF(SUM(B:B)>1364,"LOOP","STOP")

```
Sub Refresh()

Do Until Range("C2").Value = "STOP"
    Sheets("2").Calculate  
Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do some smaller tests and extrapolate.

Comment: It's more interesting if you post your code...

Comment: I posted code. I ran for the first 4 and it took a couple of seconds. I am not sure how to apply this to a much large set...

Comment: Does not a appear to be a real question, or, is a question that the OP could answer on his/her own, with some trial and error and testing.

Comment: I would guess that randomly picking 1300 distinct numbers from between 1 to 1364 might take a while... There is no "statistical" approach for how long that might be, but you could probably estimate how many iterations it might take.

Comment: There are better ways to get a set of distinct random numbers.  See [cpearosn UniqueRandomLongs](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RandomNumbers.aspx) or [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112178/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-excel-using-formula-without-vba)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the probability of this happening by chance.

Eg: choosing random numbers between 1 and 1364, the probablity of the first number being unique is 1364/1364=1 (as expected!)  The second number has a slightly lesser chance of being unique (becuase one of the possible outcomes has already been selected), ie. 1363/1364 = approx. 0.9993, and so on...

To calculate the cumulative probability, you multiply all of the probabilities together.  This doesn't look too bad at first, but as the number of values being picked increases, the cumulative probability that they'll all be unique gets **very** small!

```
Number#    Fav. outcomes   Poss. outcomes   Proab.(F/P)  CumulativeProb.
1             1364          1364              1              1 
2             1363          1364          0.9993        0.999266862170088 
 3             1362          1364          0.9985        0.997801661492419 
 4             1361          1364          0.9978        0.995607083058052 
 5             1360          1364          0.9971        0.992687414192779 
 6             1359          1364          0.9963        0.989048530709667 
 7             1358          1364          0.9956        0.984697877348775 
 8             1357          1364          0.9949        0.979644442494345 
 9             1356          1364          0.9941        0.9738987272891 
 100           1265          1364          0.9274        2.42184294266298E-02 
 200           1165          1364          0.8541        2.1388864198042E-07 
 300           1065          1364          0.7808        3.48483477273297E-16 
 400           965           1364          0.7075        4.65969192062002E-29 
 500           865           1364          0.6342        1.92148262885009E-46 
 600           765           1364          0.5609        7.31144974750256E-69 
 700           665           1364          0.4875        5.58849715194661E-97 
 800           565           1364          0.4142        1.17499140301415E-131 
 900           465           1364          0.3409        4.55604356381877E-174 
 1000          365           1364          0.2676        6.66544033524014E-226 
 1100          265           1364          0.1943        8.31996777956565E-290
```

So you can see it's probably going to take a long time....

**EDIT**: Brad has the *actual* solution: I was just trying to figure out how long it might take for the original approach to succeed (and this wouldn't fit in a comment)

Comment: seems like th better strategy is to make a list [1,1364] then remove 64 randomly. ultimately there is no need to keep guessing ad nauseum, eh?

Comment: Yes - that's the sensible approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get however many unique random numbers. You can then take that dictionary and put it into cells if you need them.

```
Dim numbersDic As New Dictionary
Dim i As Single
While numbersDic.Count < 1300
    i = Rnd()
    If Not numbersDic.Exists(i) Then
        numbersDic.Add i, i
    End If
Wend

Dim numbersArr() As Single
ReDim numbersArr(numbersDic.Count)
Dim n As Integer, Key As Variant

For Each Key In numbersDic.Keys
    numbersArr(n) = numbersDic(Key)
    n = n + 1
Next Key

Range("A1:A" & numbersDic.Count - 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(numbersArr)
```

Edit:

after re-reading your question it seems like you want to pick 1300 random numbers from [1,1364]. Why not just pick 64 random numbers and exclude them from your list? Doing the reverse seems awkward. OR are you trying to make 1300 random numbers? regardless of range?