# Creating randomized lab partner matrix in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to use Excel to generate a randomized lab partner list, without using VB (due to security settings on the PCs).

Parameters are as follows:

Number of students: 10-30, one worksheet per total number desired
Number of partners: Three for first two labs, and two for the other four-five.
Number of lab stations: 10
Repeats: Ideally none, but it is permissible for a student to have a repeat partner from one of the first two labs.
Excel version: 2007

To clarify, each student will have two labs where they share a lab station with up to two other students, giving a maximum lab size of 30 students.  After that, they will be strictly limited to two students per station, giving a maximum of 20 students.  Each student will have four of these limited labs, with there being a total of five such labs presented, to allow for either odd-numbered classes, or a class size between 21-30.

Each student is simply numbered from 1-30, so a cell could, for instance, state "5, 24" as the two students for that lab station.

True RNG is not important, and in fact, only needs to be performed once to make these matrices.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Show us what you have so far and then explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bit tricky without using VBA, but here is one approach that is OK for small groups. I have tried it using a group of just nine so that the screen shot should be readable.

The method is basic [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

```
A Start with a group of students size n represented by a list of numbers 1 to n.

B Generate a random number r in range 1 to n

C Pick the rth element from the list

D Remove the rth element from the list

E Reduce n by 1

F Repeat from B until n=1.
```

In Excel:-

Fill A2:A10 and D2:L2 with numbers 1-9

Put the following in B2 and pull down:-

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,10-A2)
```

Put this in C2 and pull down:-

```
=OFFSET(D2,0,B2-1)
```

Put this in D3 and pull down and across:-

```
=IF(D2>=$C2,E2,D2)
```

The ID's will be in column C so the first three would be in group 1, the next three in group 2 etc.

[image]

By the way, your question is a special case of generating non-repeating random numbers - see

[Generating unique random numbers without VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112178/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-excel-using-formula-without-vba)

The array formula described here does it in one step - modified slightly for this problem it would look like

```
=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:9")))=0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:9"))),RANDBETWEEN(1,(9-ROWS(C$2:C2)+1)))
```

Comment: That works great!  To the questions above, the problem is I had no idea how to do what I wanted.  I'd never considered using OFFSET.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully you can tailor it to your exact requirements.

Comment: By the way, I realised afterwards that you can have any student ID you choose in D2:L2, doesn't just have to be numbers 1-9.